# Bluetooth Dongle Not Working (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: usb, bluetooth

I've recently bought this Bluetooth dongle for my PC:
https://smile.amazon.de/gp/product/B07BFS94X4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

But the PC doesn't seem to recognise it. The Bluetooth On/Off switch in the settings app is non-functional.
In accordance to some other answers here, I installed Blueman (which I had also used on older machines). But it gives me an error message when I start it, even if I start Bluetooth via the Terminal beforehand.

Curiously, lsusb gives the same output with or without the dongle plugged in.

Edit 1: dmesg yields lots of

```
[22043.878231] RTW: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlx0013eff115a2) Enter 802.11 power save - WIFI-TRAFFIC_IDLE
[22043.878235] RTW: rtl8822b_set_FwPwrMode_cmd(wlx0013eff115a2): HW port id=0
[22043.878238] RTW: rtl8822b_set_FwPwrMode_cmd(wlx0013eff115a2): fw ps mode = LPS, drv ps mode = 2, rlbm = 1 , smart_ps = 2, allQueueUAPSD = 0
[22045.894292] RTW: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlx0013eff115a2) Leave 802.11 power save - WIFI-TRAFFIC_BUSY
[22045.894296] RTW: rtl8822b_set_FwPwrMode_cmd(wlx0013eff115a2): HW port id=0
[22045.894298] RTW: rtl8822b_set_FwPwrMode_cmd(wlx0013eff115a2): fw ps mode = ACTIVE, drv ps mode = 0, rlbm = 0 , smart_ps = 0, allQueueUAPSD = 0
```

Edit 2: lsusb yields

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2c99 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04d9:fa58 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 125f:9318 A-DATA Technology Co., Ltd.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Edit 3: I ran both lsusb and dmesg after a reboot without the WiFi Dongle with and without the Bluetooth dongle in. lsusb doesn't seem to yield any difference. Neither does dmesg, though it's still hundreds of lines so I'm not 100% sure. I'm starting to get the impression that the device is simply broken. I uploaded the dmesg results in some text files, links in comment below. I also opened a googledoc with both results in:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qSzLURsEOLgQgDkaENYOexY4Hre_gNf7YULdKT_zdqE/edit?usp=sharing

Edit 4: I ran diff with the two outputs from dmesg, and it didn't give any result, i.e. there was no difference found.

Comment: With the dongle NOT plugged in, note the final line of `dmesg`. Then plug the dongle in. Review `dmesg` again, and locate any new lines at the end that were caused by plugging in the dongle. Copy-and-paste those new lines into your Question above.

Comment: Just to be sure before I do this, I'm getting dozens of lines, is that correct? Edit: it's hundreds of lines actually

Comment: Dozens of lines indicate two possibilities: Either you are misreading the output (check the timecodes; they are in seconds since boot), or there are a LOT of errors. We don't want to see hundreds of lines back to boot. We DO want to see all lines triggered by plugging in the dongle ONCE. We don't want to see myriad lines from plugging in the dongle five times.

Comment: I pasted parts of the output in the initial comment. Slight variations of these lines are repeated lots of times.

Comment: A lot of work was done on the rtl8822 drivers during 2018 and 2019. Try a 19.10 LiveUSB, and see if the same issue occurs.

Comment: Isn't there a way to get the drivers up-to-date under 18.04? I've only installed them a few weeks ago.

Comment: Trying a 19.10 LiveUSB is an easy troubleshooting technique, not a solution. The result will rule out many possible problems (and ineffective solutions). You have not yet demonstrated that "drivers" (usually called "kernel modules" in the Linux world) are the problem, so jumping into updating those modules may or may not be effective...though you are certainly welcome to try. Finally, note that the Amazon description of the hardware does NOT claim Linux compatibility, which is the responsibility of the manufacturer (not Ubuntu). So keep track of your hardware return deadline.

Comment: I checked the FAQ and reviews on amazon, there people said it worked fine with Linux. I'm currently setting up a LiveUSB, but will probably not have time to try it out until tomorrow as it is getting late.

Comment: The messages in your question are associated with your USB wireless device, not the bluetooth. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` with the bluetooth plugged in.

Comment: added the output from lsusb

Comment: Since I'm reluctant to reinstall the WiFi dongle on a USB boot atm, I just ran dmesg without the dongle plugged in. On first glance, the outputs with and without the Bluetooth dongle look very similar, but I haven't checked thoroughly yet. I uploaded them here: https://www.file-up.org/1dagt3lxm63a
https://www.file-up.org/7nw2bfu1edir or in this googledoc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qSzLURsEOLgQgDkaENYOexY4Hre_gNf7YULdKT_zdqE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1):

If the output of `lsusb` is the same with and without plugging in the dongle, that means its clearly dead. Its not a driver issue.

Comment: It is clearly there `0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.`

Answer (score -1):

This old question came up from google search.

There can be a lot of issues with USB bluetooth dongles. In my case, plugging it directly to the PC case, and not on the USB Hub, solved the problem.